# Sharpdevelop using Mono

Tags: mono, sharpdevelop

Is it possible to run sharp develop on Linux using mono?
I have already tried it on wine but the only supported version is 2.*n*
This version does not support .Net 4.*

Comment: You can always run MonoDevelop so what's the point of using SharpDevelop and Wine?

Comment: That it doesn't support VB.net and WPF

Comment: Then why not use Windows directly? Wine is a best effort project and you simply have to help yourself in such cases.

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not.  MonoDevelop is a fork from SharpDevelop precisely because at the time SharpDevelop could not run on Mono, and that has not signifcantly changed since then.  In a way, this situation shows the flaw in Xamarin’s strategy of following MS .Net, which is a moving target.  But MonoDevelop is useful for whatever is portable in .Net, which excludes MS VB.Net & WPF.

Comment: Whomever voted down, please say what is wrong with my answer.

Comment: Voted you back up since your information is accurate.